# Ember Data does not add parameters to a post request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a resource on my rails backend using ember.js as the frontend.

In the `router.js` I have this:

```
 //...
 this.route('posts', function() {
  this.route('new');
 });
//...
```

This is `app/templates/posts/new.hbs`

```
<div>
  <label>Title</label>
   {{input type="text" value=model.title}}
</div>

 <div>
  <label>Body</label>
   {{input type="text" value=model.body}}
</div>

<div>
  <button {{action "save"}}>Save</button>
  <button {{action "cancel"}}>Cancel</button>
</div>
```

`app/routes/posts/new.js` looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({ 
  model() { 
    return {};
  },

  actions: {
    save() {
      var newPost = this.get('store').createRecord('post', this.currentModel);
      newPost.save().then((post) => {
        this.transitionTo('post', post);
      });
    },

    cancel() {
      this.transitionTo('posts');
    }
  }
});
```

This is the `post` model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  comments: DS.hasMany('comment')
});
```

When I click the `save` button on the form, I get this error on the console:

```
POST http://localhost:4200/posts 400 (Bad Request)
```

further inspecting the error on the rails server side, I find this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: post):
```

I don't know why the parameters from the form are not being sent with the POST request, what I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to return a new empty model in the model hook vs creating a new one and passing the props:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({ 
  model() { 
    return this.get('store').createRecord('post', {});
  },

  actions: {
    save() {
      this.get('currentModel').save()
      .then(post => this.transitionTo('post', post.get('id'));
    },

    cancel() {
      this.transitionTo('posts');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the post model?

Comment: I have added the post model.

Comment: Could you recreate the issue on [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) or better yet put the repo on github? The code you posted looks in order